# Getting Form Values on submit after Javascript validation failure

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

First off the code I'm talking about is part of a marked assignment so I can't post the entire thing in case someone else from the course finds this.

The general gist however is that I have a form:

```
<form action="yo!PHPlinkhere" method="post" onsubmit="return callAllFunctions();">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Age" name="Age" size="3" maxlength="3"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

To clarify there is more than one `input` in the form this is a cut down version, the rest are the same format as this.

There is then `javascript code` that makes sure the age is between 1-100 and passes back true or false.  The problem is that if false comes back and you then change the age to be within 1-100 and hit submit again the new value isn't passed the old one is kept.

I'm new to both HTML and JavaScript so I'm not sure if the problem is how the value is being acquired and then stored in JavaScript or sent in HTML.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S yo!PHPlinkhere is just filler and the actual HTML file has the real link there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function callAllFunctions() {
  var age = document.getElementById("Age").value;
  if (age > 100 || age <= 0) {
    console.log(age);
    return false;
  }
  console.log(age);
  document.getElementById("resultAge").innerHTML = age;
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="Age" id="Age" size="3" maxlength="3" required>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return  callAllFunctions()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<div id="resultAge"></div>
```

May be this will help.

HTML File

```
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return callAllFunctions()">
      <table>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="number" name="Age" id="Age" size="3" maxlength="3" required></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</form>
<div id="resultAge"></div> // you can get what value is passing
```

Js File

```
function callAllFunctions() {
    var age = document.getElementById("Age").value;
    if (age > 100 || age <= 0) {
        console.log(age);
        return false;
    }
    console.log(age);
    document.getElementById("resultAge").innerHTML = age;
    return true;
}
```

You can see console is logging all Age value that is passing but only get submitted if it is true and that is show in `<div class="resultAge"></div>` using `innerHTML`.

In code snippet just to show it working I'm using `onclick` so you can see value in `<div class="resultAge"></div>`

Comment: Thank you for the help it actually turned out to be a problem with how I was storing all the true or false replies in an array.  Your solution lead me down the right road.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
function callAllFunctions() {
    var age = document.getElementById("Age").value;
    return (age > 100 || age <= 0)? false :
    document.getElementById("resultAge").innerHTML = age;   
}
```